# jquery error: a function is not a function?

Tags: jquery

How is it possible that, being 'colonna' a simple string:

```
$('td.' + colonna).css('background-color','#ffddaa');
```

works correctly highlighting the background of the interesting cells, and:

```
$('td.' + colonna).contains('Catia').css('background-color','#ffddaa');
```

produces the error: "$('td.' + colonna).contains is not a function"?

Someone has an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it should be something like:

```
$('td.' + colonna + ":contains('Catia')").css('background-color','#ffddaa');
```

Comment: I'm confused because of this: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contains

I have been learning jQuery through "jQuery in Action" (too lazy to look up a link; it's a popular book though) and in my Oct. 2008 edition on p.45 they list a "contains" function.  Both their example, and the one I linked to above from the jQuery docs, generate the OP's error ("not a function").  Did there used to be a .contains function that maybe got removed?  Or did it get added after 1.2.1, the version used in the book's sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the specific answer, but it sounds like you would gain a lot by using a good JS debugger. I'd recommand [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Explanations on how to use it here: http://getfirebug.com/js.html

Like this you will be able to see the DOM, the different functions availables. If it doesn't fix it you'll still be able to post a more precise question.

Sorry for not being more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way (way!) past due, but I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785274/what-happened-to-the-jquery-contains-traversal-method) and it would appear that the net result is "old versions of JQuery had a `.contains()` method, but it has been deprecated."  Yay for breaking your API!