# What happened to the jQuery "contains" traversal method?

Tags: jquery

A follow-up to the comment I just posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971477/jquery-error-a-function-is-not-a-function/971522#971522)... I ran this in Firebug:

```
var l = []; for(f in $('div')){l.push(f);}; l.sort(); alert(l.join("\n"));
```

just to make sure I wasn't going crazy, and "contains" is not, in fact, a method of the jQuery wrapped set.  But the [jquery docs page](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contains) says it is.  What gives?  Was there a "contains" method that got deprecated?  Is it new, and the version I'm testing with (1.2.1) doesn't have it yet?  Is there a better way to find this information than asking on SO?

Comment: The `contains` page is still available directly by your URL, but isn't listed in the Traversing overview page (http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing).

Comment: Just goes to show that when you name a method with a common English word (like "contains") it makes things harder when you're searching for information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was deprecated on 1.2, and completely replaced by the filter expression on 1.3.

More info:

- [Removed Functionality](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2#Removed_Functionality)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in [jQuery 1.1.3.1](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.1.3.1.js), `contains` was a supported function, along with `eq`, `lt`, and `gt`, as an alias for a call to `filter()` using those CSS filters.  As of jQuery 1.2, the method no longer is present in the code.

So it would seem the documentation is for the previous version, that method was indeed removed from jQuery.  Note that in the table of contents for [Traversing](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing), it's not listed.  Of course, using `filter()` instead will work as it always has.

Comment: I'd submit a ticket to their bugtrack to have deprecated methods marked as "deprecated" in the docs, but I can't be arsed to create an account on their website just to do that.  I guess nobody else can, either :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on one of the powerful features of jQuery, the traversal methods.

http://www.jaftalks.com/Home/Show/Introduction-to-JQuery-Traversal-Methods